# How to Access Environment Object Inside the Observable Class --- Swift 5

Tags: swift5

class NotificationStore:  ObservableObject {
    @Published var notification: [NotificationModel] = []

```
@EnvironmentObject var people: PeopleStore


init() {
    getNotifyDetails()
}

/// API for news list wilth information
func getNotifyDetails() {
    Api().getNotification {(notify) in
        self.notification = [notify]

        switch self.notification[0].serviceCallStatus {

        case 23:  
            self.people.isLogged = true

        case 56: // 400 Error Response
            print("NOTIFICATION Error: Validation error On data")

        case 57: // 500 Error Response
            print("NOTIFICATION Error: Internal Servcer error")

        default:
            print("default Error")
        }

    }
}
```

}

//Error
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type PeopleStore found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for PeopleStore may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-39.4.3/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55

2020-05-06 09:47:50.422921+0530 StayHome[1509:70499] Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type PeopleStore found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for PeopleStore may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-39.4.3/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55
(lldb)